# Multiplying two power series with negative indices

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, power-series

Just wondering whether there is any special way (formula) to multiply to power series which contain negative indices, i.e. $\bigg(\sum\limits_{i=-m}^{\infty}a_ix^i\bigg)\bigg(\sum\limits_{j=-n}^{\infty}b_jx^j\bigg)$? Or the only way to do it is just by shifting indices? Cheers!

Comment: I think that shifting indices is a very sensible strategy: you have $x^{-m-n}$ multiplying the product of two ordinary power series…

Comment: @Lubin: Hmm what do you mean on that $x^{-m-n}$ part?

Comment: As an example, say the first factor is $a_{-3}x^{-3}a_{-2}x^{-2}+\cdots$. Then you rewrite it as $x^{-3}(a_{-3}+a_{-2}x+a_{-1}x^2+\cdots)$ — what’s in parentheses here is an ordinary power series. That’s all. Of course I assume you know how to multiply things in the power series ring $R[[x]]$. Yes?

Comment: @Lubin: Ah ok! Yep sure I know how to do that. :-) Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

As a formal power series, the product is $\sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}} c_kx^k$, where $$c_k = \sum_{i+j = k} a_ib_j$$
The trick is that since $a_i = 0$ for $i < -m$ and $b_j = 0$ for $j < -n$, the sum defining $c_k$ is actually finite. More precisely, it could me written as the finite sum
$$c_k = \sum_{(i,j)\in S_k} a_ib_j \space\text{with}\space S_k = \{(i,j) \mid i+j =k, -m \leqslant i \leqslant k+n \space\text{and}\space -n \leqslant j \leqslant k+m\}$$